# Button with a variable X position should'nt be upon the logo

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have two buttons in my header with variable X position, like this :

[image]

But if the user resize the browser window to a too small width, the "A" and "B" buttons comes upon the logo (Like in third exemple). How could I avoid that ?

P.S. Sorry if my english is not that good

Comment: please add at least a http://jsfiddle.net/ or a code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert the logo in a div and from the css made his position relative and float it to the left, then you should do the same with the buttons. I've made an example for you there, maybe you can also set a min-width

http://jsfiddle.net/n3gmsgto/

HTML:

```
<div id="headbar">
   <div id="logo">Logo</div>
   <div id="A">A</div>
   <div id="B">B</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headbar{
   background-color:#0099ff; 
   height:100px;   
   width:100%
}

#logo{
   position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    //or maybe min-width:x%;
  }

#A{
   position:relative;
    float:left;
     width:15%;
  }

#B{
   position:relative;
    float:left;
     width:15%;
  }
```

Is also possible to arrange them in different ways to obtain similar results.